# Windows 7 Openssl 64 bit error when installing pyopenssl

Tags: python, windows, openssl, scrapy, pyopenssl

i want to install scrapy, however it cannot complete install due to a pyopenssl errror when using pip. its a 64 bit machinr.

I continue to receive the error.

```
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\pyOpenSSL.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
error: Could not find 'openssl.exe'
```

So I searched around for an answer to instal openssl for 64bit. I found [openssl](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)
Then I installed.

```
Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1
```

However I still receive the same error when tring to install pyopenssl, any ideas?

Comment: unrelated: I would not use scrapy with windows since twisted (a dependency of scrapy) can be hard to work with on windows.

Comment: @DrColossos any suggestions on a good scraping language/framework. Saw this question the answers are a little dated (2008) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping. Interesting though from a later post found http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Scrapy is fine and it will run on windows with propaly lots of work. I'm just saying that you might think about using it with linux since it supports (and setup is easier as well) much of the stuff (including OpenSSL) way better than Windows does